# homework on scheme

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme

how to design a function content which
 inputs a single list of atoms lat and which returns
 the content of lat.Thus the content  of '(a b c a b c d d) is '(a b c d).

Comment: which language are you talking about?

Comment: @Sarfraz, the title of the post is "homework on scheme"...

Comment: @ki, what have you tried so far?  You're unlikely to get any help without showing us what you've already tried.

Comment: You might like to define what "lat" stands for.

Comment: took off the recursion tag as the solution doesn't need to be recursive.

Answer (score 3):

The procedure `content` below should get you what you need.

```
(define (work x y)
  (if (null? (cdr x))
      (if (in? (car x) y)
          y 
          (cons (car x) y))
      (if (in? (car x) y)
          (work (cdr x) y)
          (work (cdr x) (cons (car x) y)))))

(define (in? x y)
  (if (null? y)
      #f
      (if (equal? x (car y))
          #t
          (in? x (cdr y)))))

(define (content x) (work x (list)))
```

The procedure `content` accepts a list as a parameter.  It sends the list to another procedure called `work`.  This procedure processes the list and adds the items in the list to a new list (if they are not already in the new list).  The `work` procedure makes use of yet another procedure called `in`, which checks to see if an item is a member of a list.

My solution essentially divides your problem into two sub-problems and makes use of procedures which operate at a lower level of abstraction than your original problem.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Eric - honestly, that code formatting is the most unlike Lisp you can get without adding begin/end keywords. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541407/lisp-code-formatting, for instance

Comment: I imagine that the reason he seemed so hostile was because you were providing this code to a person asking for homework. I suppose his teacher probably expects proper formatting.

Comment: that's the point ... "proper" to you may not be "proper" to me

Answer (score 1):

It is PLT Scheme solution:

```
(define (is_exists list element)
 (cond
   [(empty? list) false]
   [else
     (cond 
       [(= (first list) element) true]
       [else (is_exists (rest list) element)])]))

(define (unique list target)
  (cond 
    [(empty? list) target]
    [else
     (cond 
       [(is_exists target (first list)) (unique (rest list) target)]
       [else (unique (rest list) (cons (first list) target))])]))

(define (create_unique list)
        (unique list empty))
```

Check it:

```
> (define my_list (cons '1 (cons '2 (cons '3 (cons '2 (cons '1 empty))))))
> my_list
(list 1 2 3 2 1)
> (create_unique my_list)
(list 3 2 1)
```

Comment: Isn't the whole point of `cond` that you don't need to chain else-clauses?  :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about little schemer style,

```
(define (rember-all a lat)
  (cond
    ((null? lat) '())
    ((eq? a (car lat)) (rember-all a (cdr lat)))
    (else (cons (car lat) (rember-all a (cdr lat))))))

(define (content lat)
  (cond
    ((null? lat) '())
    (else (cons (car lat)
                (content (rember-all (car lat) (cdr lat)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Start from a procedure that simply creates a copy of the passed-in list (very easy to do):

```
(define (unique-elements seq)
  (define (loop ans rest)
    (cond ((null? rest) ans)
          (else
           (loop (cons (car rest) ans)
                 (cdr rest)))))
  (loop '() seq))
```

To ensure that the output list's elements are unique, we should skip the CONS if the head of REST is already a member of ANS. So we add another condition to do just that:

```
;;; Create list containing elements of SEQ, discarding duplicates.
(define (unique-elements seq)
  (define (loop ans rest)
    (cond ((null? rest) ans)
          ((member (car rest) ans)  ; *new*
           (loop ans (cdr rest)))   ; *new*
          (else
           (loop (cons (car rest) ans)
                 (cdr rest)))))
  (loop '() seq))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function takes in a list and returns a new list with only the unique inputs of it's argument using recursion:

```
(defun uniq (list)
    (labels ((next (lst new)
                (if (null lst)
                    new
                    (if (member (car lst) new)
                        (next   (cdr lst) new)
                        (next   (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) new))))))
        (next list ())))
```

As was mentioned in the comments, common lisp already has this function:

```
(defun uniq (list)
    (remove-duplicates list))
```

Comment: But where is the fun in that? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (remove-duplicates aloc)
  (cond
    ((empty? aloc) '())
    (else (cons (first aloc)
                (remove-duplicates
                 (filter (lambda (x)
                           (cond
                             ((eq? x (first aloc)) #f)
                             (else #t)))
                         (rest aloc)))))))
```